# How obfuscates android project using proguard in eclipse?

Tags: android, proguard

How use proguard to obfuscated android app.When export application for apk I get following problem.

**Problem**

```
[2013-09-26 13:16:53 - Fishing_log] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-09-26 13:16:53 - Fishing_log] proguard.ParseException: Value of system property 'init' is undefined in 'string/app_name { <init>' in line 2 of file 'C:\Users\owner\workspace8\Fishing_log\bin\proguard.txt',
[2013-09-26 13:16:53 - Fishing_log]   included from argument number 6
[2013-09-26 13:16:53 - Fishing_log]     at proguard.ConfigurationParser.replaceSystemProperties(ConfigurationParser.java:1153)
[2013-09-26 13:16:53 - Fishing_log]     at proguard.ConfigurationParser.file(ConfigurationParser.java:1113)
[2013-09-26 13:16:53 - Fishing_log]     at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseIncludeArgument(ConfigurationParser.java:242)
[2013-09-26 13:16:53 - Fishing_log]     at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:150)
[2013-09-26 13:16:53 - Fishing_log]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:476)
```

How i resolve this issue?

I added following codes in **project.properties** and **proguard-project.txt**

**project.properties**

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

**proguard-project.txt**

```
 -injars lib
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-dontnote
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe, java.lang.management.ManagementFactory, org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser, org.json.JSONObject, org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator, org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory, com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
   native <methods>;
}
 -keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}
 -keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
 -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
#Keep the R
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The build process lets the tool `aapt` write out a configuration file `proguard.txt`, which is then passed to ProGuard. However, the current version of aapt has a bug -- If I remember correctly, it doesn't handle XML files with class names that refer to string definitions (in `res/values/strings.xml`). For the time being, you should avoid such string definitions.

Note that the file `proguard-project.txt` should essentially be empty, since the bulk of the configuration is already specified in the shared configuration file `${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt`. The build process also automatically specifies all `-injars`, `-outjars`, and `-libraryjars` for you.

Comment: this problem create due to ACRA.First android:name="" declare in res/values/string.xml.I had changed to hard coded string & this problem solve.